# Как записать таблицу умножения в элемент на странице?

Tags: javascript, таблицы

```js
<script>
    function crTable() {
        let tAdd = document.getElementById('tableU');
        if (true) {
            tAdd.innerHTML += '<table>';
            if (x < 9) {
                table.innerHTML += '<tr>';
                for (let x; x < 9;x++) {
                    if (x = 3) {
                        table.innerHTML += '</tr><tr>';
                    } else {
                        for (let y = 1; y < 9; y++) {
                            let el = '<td>' + x + 'x' + y + ' = ' + x * y + '</td>';
                            table.innerHTML += el;
                        }
                        }
                } 
            }
            }
        }

</script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html"  charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="crTable()" value="Показать таблицу умножения" style="width:250px;font-size:15px;"/>
    <div id="tableU">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function crTable() {
  let tAdd = document.getElementById('tableU');
  let table = '<table border=1><tr>';
  for (let x = 1; x < 11; x++) {
    for (let y = 1; y < 11; y++) {
      let el = '<td>' + x + 'x' + y + ' = ' + x * y + '</td>';
      table += el;
    }
    table += '</tr><tr>';
  }
  table += '</tr></table>';
  //console.log(table);
  tAdd.innerHTML = table;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="crTable()" value="Показать таблицу умножения" style="width:250px;font-size:15px;" />
<div id="tableU"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let res = ''
for (let i=1; i<=10; ++i) {
  for (let j=1; j<=10; ++j) {
   res += ' ' + String(i*j).padStart(3, ' ');
  }
  res += '\n';
}

document.getElementById('mul_tbl').innerText = res;
```

```css
h4{padding: 0 5em;}
```

```html
<h4>Таблица умножения</h4>
<pre id=mul_tbl></pre>
```